# How to define "inflation" in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to learn Android and I don't understand what `Inflate` really does. I've seen different examples on which it is used for inserting a layout inside another but I'm not sure on where it is good to be used.

Can anyone help with good examples?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Inflation" is a term that refers to parsing XML and turning it into UI-oriented data structures. You can inflate a view hierarchy, a menu structure, and other types of resources. Often this is done behind the scenes by the framework (when you call `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, for instance). A typical case when you explicitly inflate something yourself is when creating menus, as described in the guide subject [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Comment: Also all XML is converted to *binary* XML at compile time as it is much more efficient than parsing a text representation.

Comment: @Joseph - Indeed. That optimization, though, is done automatically during the build process and is basically invisible (and mostly irrelevant) to the programmer. But good to point out in case someone is tempted to write their own parser. :-)

Comment: Also worth pointing out that due to this you can't run the inbuilt inflater on anything but binary XML files (I think in theory it has an option which should allow you to do it on normal XML, but it doesn't work). Still I'd like to see an app that downloaded layouts from the net and applied them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply understanding:
"inflate" is a term in Android to **convert a layout XML file** into **its corresponding View objects**. It is used in **menuInflater.inflate(...)** or **layoutInflater.inflate(...)**